# Does dart support perl style regular expression and match operator syntax?

Tags: regex, dart

Can you write anything like:

```
string =~ /^.s*(.\S+)/;
print "First word is '$1'";
```

What is the syntax in dart? Or must one use the raw objects?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are no regexp literals and match operators in Dart. So yes, you have to use the RegExp object and its siblings.

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunate, since this is one of the things I love about perl and ruby, and hate about java. Maybe it will come in future. Hope so.

Comment: @Jim: Not any time soon, apparently: [ref](http://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=289)

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure about dart. But from here

http://www.dartlang.org/docs/dart-up-and-running/ch03.html#ch03-strings-and-regular-expressions

it looks like the syntax is same as any other language.

Comment: Syntax of the regexes *themselves* is the same as JavaScript (which is compatible with Perl and other Perl-derived flavors, but nowhere near as feature-rich).  What Jim's asking about is the syntax of the language itself, like regex literals and the match operator, `~=`.

Comment: Exactly. I think there are minor difference between PCRE (perl combatible REs) and javascript REs, but Dart has to be js compatible.

Answer (score 1):

Dart doesn't have literal regexp syntax:

```python
/foo\s*\(bar\)/
```

But it does have raw strings, and you should use them:

```dart
new RegExp(r"foo\s*\(bar\)");
```

without raw strings, you would have to double the backslashes and (if you remembered to do that) you would have:

```dart
new RegExp("foo\\s*\\(bar\\)");
```